# How to increase c++ code's efficiency which is using threads?

Tags: c++

I have to use C++ code whose speed is too slow perhaps it is using the function omp_set_num_threads. I'm not familiar with C++. I only need this code to generate input data but I dont have idea what goes inside this code. Output result is such that samples having a column of length 36 are stacked vertically, I want to speed up my code. When I put ompt_set_num_threads(1) performance improves somehow. I want to increase the efficiency with minor changes because i'm not familiar with c++. I read that parallel computation slows down this efficiency. How to get rid of it with minor changes

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    omp_set_num_threads(8); 

    if (init(argc, argv)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Program ended.\n");
    exit(2);
}
```

Comment: Threading stuff only makes sense if some threads are waiting for input or if you have very heavy computation, that you can split into smaller pieces. In very simple cases like the one above, overhead of creating threads will far outweigh any gains from splitting work.

Comment: Yes I have to generate huge amount of data. But this threading slows down computation how to get rid of it?

Comment: Multithreading is a complex solution and the associated code needs to *carefully* be designed in accordance. Multithreading is rarely a solution you can slap on after the fact to go faster.

Comment: Every thread has an overhead for setup and maintenance.  There is no guarantee that the threads will run on separate cores.  There is a possibility that the threads can be scheduled on the same CPU as the main thread, in a round-robin fashion (which may not show any performance improvement).